# LDAP query from Java is slow

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap, jndi

We are having some performance issues with our LDAP and out Java Server. Whenever we call our LDAP query, which looks like this **(&(objectclass=person)(department=0128)(departmentNumber=1))** it takes about 2000 milliseconds, which is too slow for us.

However if we perform a search, using the same query with a standard LDAP browser (eg. the LDAP Admin program from the web), it only takes a few milliseconds.

Our simplified code is below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {


    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>(); // NOPMD

    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://abc123.muc:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=myproject,OU=projectusers,DC=COM");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "asdf");
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

    LdapContext iLeanLdapCtx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

    //TIME TO CREATE CONTEXT = 40ms

    String filter = "(&(objectclass=person)(department=0128)(departmentNumber=1))";


    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = iLeanLdapCtx.search("O=computers,DC=COM", filter, null);

    //TIME TO SEARCH WITH FILTER = 2000ms

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results2 = iLeanLdapCtx.search("O=computers,DC=COM", filter, null);

    //2nd TIME TO SEARCH WITH FILTER = 2000ms
}
```

Is there some initialisation problem going on here?

I thought instantiating the LdapContext should have solved all that time intensive stuff. **ldapCtx.search** takes about 2 seconds, and if I call it again, it is still 2 seconds. So the initial search does not seem to do any initialisation. And even if the query is simply just that slow, why would the other LDAP browser I have go so fast?

Comment: Do you have indexes on `department` and `departmentNumber`?

Comment: Time your search with a known good tool like `ldapsearch` with the search parameters in the LDAP client application code to get a baseline (avoid LDAP browsers for this task). Then try the same search with the UnboundID LDAP SDK and compare those results to the results from the known good tool and JNDI.

Comment: thats exactly the problem i have. If i used the paramters in an LDAP browser its lightening fast, but if i have them in the application code its slow. Is it because the LDAP browser is doing some kind of caching?

Comment: Try using a LDAP Proxy and see what difference is there in the calls made